Нужна ли запятая перед "или" в данном случае
Нужна ли запятая перед "или" в данном случае?

Вы с ним друзья, потому что оба так решили, или ты поставила
ультиматум?


Правильно:
Вы с ним друзья, потому что оба так решили, или ты поставила ультиматум?
Пояснение
Это сложное предложение с подчинительной (союз ПОТОМУ ТО) и сочинительной связью (союз ИЛИ), три предикативные основы.
Правило для ССП, по которому вопросительная интонация может объединить два простых предложения, здесь применить нельзя ввиду грамматической неоднородности СПП и простого предложения.
Если не поставить запятую перед ИЛИ,  то сложное предложение будет делиться на две части подчинительным союзом ПОТОМУ ЧТО, а это некорректно.
